# Why do ten rows (Figure_1) correspond to 2 bits (Figure_2) in a sequence logo?

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, sequence-analysis

Following [this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/what-is-aligned-sequences-and-consensus-sequence-in-the-context-of-sequence), I'm confused with the [computation of sequence logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_logo)

Following data comes from the book "[Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/) (Figure_1)"

[image]

here is the corresponding [sequence logo](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/9089/4962) (Figure_2).

[image]

ten rows represent sequences of DNA (e.g. row 1 could be a human sequence, row 2 could be the equivalent mouse sequence etc.)

Each column corresponds to a particular position.

Why do ten rows (Figure_1) correspond to 2 bits (Figure_2)?

Comment: You can find on e.g., [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_logo) how a sequence logo is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bits are not frequencies. If a position only contains an A (position 3 for example) then you would need 2 questions (bits) to derive that information without a priori knowledge.

1. Is it a G or C? if no > then it is a A or T
2. Is it T? If no then it is an A

Position 1 can be derived by 1 question only:

1. is it a G or C?  If no then it is an A or T

In this case the number of bits can be calculated using the frequenci)es.

**For 4 bases, A only (100%)**:

4 * -0.25 * log2(0.25) - (-1 * log2(1)) = 2 (bits)

**For 8 letters, A only (100%)**:

8 * -1/8 * log(1/8)- (-1 * log2(1)) = 3 (bits)

**Mixed base possibility (A/T 50% each) with 4 bases**:

4 * -0.25 * log2(0.25) - (-0.5 * log2(0.5)+-0.5 * log2(0.5)) = 1 (bit)

As mentioned in the comments, you can follow the wiki link for an example.

Or, an example with a little more explanation from the biology SE site.

[sequence logo calcuation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64368/how-to-determine-the-height-bits-in-a-sequence-logo)

Hopes this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this specific case, `4 bases` is being used, since there are a,t,g,c 4 Nucleotides in total, right?

Comment: correct. That is this part: 4 * -0.25 * log2(0.25) of the equation.