# How to compute the Shannon entropy for a strand of DNA?

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, sequence-analysis

I'm confused by the [computation](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/9091/4962) of sequence logo. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_logo#Logo_creation) gives a process about this without a concrete example.

Let's just consider DNA, so there are 4 bases (nucleic acids).

The following data comes from the book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective (Figure 1)"

[image]

The Shannon entropy of position $i$ is:

${\displaystyle H_{i}=-\sum _{b=a}^{t}f_{b,i}\times \log _{2}f_{b,i}}$

Where ${\displaystyle f_{b,i}}$ is the relative frequency of base

This [post](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/9094/4962) is computing position 3, where it seems that the relative frequency of `a` is 100%, and the relative frequency of 3 other bases are 0%.

Now, how do you calculate the Shannon entropy of position 3? It seems to be 0, which is apparently incorrect, where am I wrong?

Comment: Note that the frequency is always in the interval [0,1] instead of [0,100]. H is 0 for columns with only one symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you think the entropy of 0 is incorrect? It intuitively makes sense, as there is no uncertainty about the base at position 3, and thus there is no entropy.

However, what is plotted in a sequence logo isn't the entropy, but rather a measure of the "decrease in uncertainty" as the sequence is aligned. This is calculated by taking the entropy at this position if we randomly aligned sequences ($H_g(L)$), and subtracting from it the entropy of the alignment ($H_g(s)$): 
$$
R_{sequence}=H_g(L) - H_s(L)
$$

The entropy at position 3 based on a random alignment is calculated by assuming there are 4 equally likely events (one for each base), and thus:
$$
\begin{align*} 
H_g(L) & = -((1/4 \times -2) + (1/4 \times -2) + (1/4 \times -2) + (1/4 \times -2)) \\
H_g(L) & = 2
\end{align*}
$$
Notably, $H_g(L)$ will always be 2 when dealing with nucleotide sequences.

So in your example, we have:
$$
\begin{align*} 
R_{sequence}&=H_g(L) - H_s(L) \\
R_{sequence}&=2 - 0 \\
R_{sequence}&=2 \text{ bits of entropy}
\end{align*}
$$

Finally, to work out the height of each base at each position in the logo, we multiply the frequency of that base by the overall information gain $R_{sequence}$. In this case the frequency of the base A at position 3 is of course 1:
$$
\begin {align*}
H(b,l) &=f(b, l) \times R_{sequence} \\
H(A, 3) &= f(a, 3) \times 2 \\
&= 1 \times 2 \\
&= 2
\end{align*}
$$

Source: [Sequence logos: a new way to display consensus sequences.
 (Thomas D. Schneider, R. Michael Stephens, 1990)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC332411/)

Note: I've excluded the correction factor $e(n)$ from the overall information-gain calculation for the sake of simplicity. Refer to the paper above for an explanation of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "g" mean/represent/come from in $H_g(L)$

Comment: I'm not sure. My guess is g=genome and s=sequence(ing) but that's pure conjecture since the paper doesn't spell it out

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And does L mean/represent/come from `location` since the paper says "at various positions (L)".

Comment: Yes, that would be my assumption. This is important to include in the equation because it's only calculating the information at a single position. The authors propose another equation for an entire sequence (which is just summing these per-position scores)

Comment: Thanks a lot. And last question, does R come from/represent/mean acids?

Comment: I don't know. But also I think you're putting too much importance on the authors' choice of variables. You could write any of these equations with different letters and they would be just as correct.